# How to hardcode answers to multiple prompted questions following a single command in a bash script?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, scripting, teamcity, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm setting up automation with TeamCity and Elastic Beanstalk, so in my script, I want to run

```
eb init
```

Which then prompts the question of which region I am in, and then what application I want to use. How to I hardcode in answers for both questions?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe `eb` has flags you can use to specify the region?

Comment: I just want to answer "3" (for region 3) and <the name of the app I'm deploying>
This probably isn't specific to EB or Teamcity but I just tagged them in case there was some way around this I don't know about

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for `eb` or the tools in general to see if they allow you to specify the region and app via arguments or environment variables?

Comment: From [the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-init.html), you should be able to give the application name after `eb` on the command line.

Comment: @MinaHan Automatically answering "3" is fragile (what if the options change? what if it starts asking something else?). It's much better to provide the information using command line parameters or config files.

Comment: If it's not possible to specify everything on the command line as the others have suggested, this would likely be a good place for an `expect` script so you can at least make sure you're answering the right question.  Using the command line arguments would be better and should be preferred though

Comment: @thatotherguy would you say it would maybe be a better idea to read the output and then write something to choose from those options?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: @MinaHan It's better, but still way worse than using the tool correctly. You should only ever try to read output and write responses when the tool does not support what you want to do in a robust way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `eb` just reads from stdin:

```
eb init <<END_OF_ANSWERS
3
$app_name
END_OF_ANSWERS
```

If it reads directly from the terminal, `expect` would be a good choice.